# Why is $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$ equal to the number of integers between $1$ and $n$ that are divisible by $m$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

For example, there are $50$ integers between $1$ an $100$ that are divisible by $2$ because $\lfloor 100/2 \rfloor=50$.

Why is this the case in general? Does it have to do with equivalence relations and the equivalence principle? Partitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lfloor n/m\rfloor$

$n\over m$ is nothing but *the number of 'm's required to get 'n'*

$\lfloor n/m\rfloor$ is nothing but *the integral number of 'm's required to reach as close as possible to 'n'*.

So, Your statement is directly obtained from this.

Another way to look at it-

The number of integers divisible by *m* between $0$ and $km$ is equal to $ (k-1) $

If $km$ is the closest to $n$ from the lower end, then, $\lfloor n/m\rfloor$ = $k$.

$(k-1)$ if you strictly follow the *between* rule.$ k $ if you include the boundaries. Strictly speaking, there are only $49$ integers between $1$ and $100$ that are divisible by $2$.

Comment: Can you be a bit more rigorous?

Comment: @AlJebr i hope I was able to explain it better. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For natural m and real x there is a unique integer n such that $nm \le x < m(n +1) $.  Thus [x/m] = n.  The set of multiples of m that are less then x is {m, 2m, ... mn}.  Which has exactly n elements.